# Regex, Separate according to punctuation R?

Tags: r, regex

I know this is a `regex` question, which has probably been answered but I cannot figure out the answer to this particular question. I have a dataset of 5000 addresses, and some of the addresses are presented as:

```
199 REEDSDALE ROAD MILTON, MA (42.252352, -71.075213)
2014 WASHINGTON STREET NEWTON, MA (42.332339, -71.246592)
75 FRANCIS STREET BOSTON, MA (42.335954, -71.107661)
235 NORTH PEARL STREET BROCKTON, MA (42.09707, -71.065645)
41 HIGHLAND AVENUE WINCHESTER, MA (42.465496, -71.121408)
```

The first comma is the separation of the address city from the state, but also there is latitude and longitude coordinates. I am interested in getting the coordinates into two columns, latitude and longitude as

```
lat        lon
42.252352  -71.075213
42.332339  -71.246592
42.335954  -71.107661
42.09707   -71.065645
42.465496  -71.121408
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to extract the numeric part with a regex lookaround

```
library(tidyverse)
data_frame(lat = str_extract(lines, "(?<=\\()-?[0-9.]+"), 
           lon = str_extract(lines, "-?[0-9.]+(?=\\))"))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  lat       lon       
#  <chr>     <chr>     
#1 42.252352 -71.075213
#2 42.332339 -71.246592
#3 42.335954 -71.107661
#4 42.09707  -71.065645
#5 42.465496 -71.121408
```

---

Or with `read.csv` after removing the characters until the `(`, including the `(` and `)` (at the end) with `gsub`, making the `,` as separator for the `read.csv` to split into two columns

```
read.csv(text = gsub("^[^(]+\\(|\\)$", "", lines), header=FALSE, 
          col.names = c("lat", "lon"))
#    lat       lon
#1 42.25235 -71.07521
#2 42.33234 -71.24659
#3 42.33595 -71.10766
#4 42.09707 -71.06565
#5 42.46550 -71.12141
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines("file.txt")
```

Comment: Nice regex. What does `-?` signify?